# Is it possible to use numpy input with the keras generator flow_from_directory?

Tags: keras, input, deep-learning, concatenation, generator

Can keras generator use numpy input flow_from_directory?

Generally speaking, we have already classified the folders, and then use the flow_from_directory (ImageDataGenerator) of the keras generator to generate the generator, but these are generally image files

What I want to know is, if the classification is also done in another folder, but the picture is not numpy, if this can generate a numpy generator, and then concatenate with the picture of flow_from_directory is feasible?

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        './input/for-norm/pic/training', 
        target_size=(224,224),
        batch_size=batch_size, 
        class_mode='categorical'
        )
```

This is a generator of pictures, I don't know if it can be integrated with numpy.